# Why my jquery td click event reacts slow on Chrome?

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, optimization

I have a big table (about 500 rows and 7 columns).
My code just has to check the table cell which I click on (it adds class "reserved" to clicked cell, this class does some simple border manipulation).

It works smoothly on Firefox and Opera, but it sucks on Chrome (I mean I have to wait about a second before the cell's border changes) - can you suggest me a way to fix it?

The first IFs are for some other checkings, but it's just checks the state of this particular clicked cell.

```
$("td").click( function() 
{
    if($(this).attr('system') !=  1)
    {
        if($(this).attr("reserved") != "1" && $(this).attr("reserved") != "2")
        {
            if($(this).attr("_checked")=="1")
            {
                $(this).addClass("reserved"); // here it changes border color
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: I'd be curious if setting a variable for the element helps:  var td = $(this)

Comment: Tiny thing, but you could put all of your if's in one big statement instead of doing sub-ifs, like `if($(this).attr('system') != 1 && $(this).attr('reserved') != "1") . . .` etc

Comment: Also, if you're using 1.8, you could see if $("table").on("click","td", function() {}) gives you better performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try caching the selector:

```
$("td").click( function() 
{
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.attr('system') !=  1)
    {
        if($this.attr("reserved") != "1" && $this.attr("reserved") != "2")
        {
            if($this.attr("_checked")=="1")
            {
                $this.addClass("reserved"); // here it changes border color
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: I did it, but unfortunately it didn't help - or it did in very small part : ) Anyway, thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you could try to "flatten" the condition like that:

```
$("td").click( function() 
{
    if ($(this).attr('system') != 1 &&
        $(this).attr("reserved") != "1" &&
        $(this).attr("reserved") != "2" &&
        $(this).attr("_checked") == "1")
    {
        $(this).addClass("reserved"); // here it changes border color
    }
}
```

and see if it helps.

Comment: This would make it more readable but it wouldn't change the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using delegated events as they have a lot less overhead when many elements must be monitored.

```
$('#yourTableID').on('click', 'td', function(event) {

  .. 

});
```